# how to connect AudioClip at local file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audioclip

I downloaded the .mp3 file from the server and stored it in my android persistentDataPath. But I do not know how to connect .mp3 files to AudioClip.
Please let me know if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: sorry..
I found the answer. I did not know there was www.audioClip.
I can use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments `WWW` now supports .mp3 files making it the way to go.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public string url;
    public AudioSource source;
    void Start() {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.clip = www.audioClip;
    }
    void Update() {
        if (!source.isPlaying && source.clip.isReadyToPlay)
            source.Play();

    }
}
```

---

*Original answer:*

Audio clip doesn't accept a file. It accepts an array of floats.

You can use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20a%20MP3%20to%20WAV) to convert the compressed MP3 to a WAV file.

```
using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;
// ....

using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3File))
{
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, reader);
}
```

You will then need to read the wave file which will basically have a header followed by the chunk data. The chunk data can be converted to a float and sent to your audio clip.

Comment: You can use WWW class as it is built in and this task does not require external libraries.

Comment: Last I checked WWW doesn't support .mp3

Comment: It does and I use it all the time!

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know they added support for MP3.

Comment: Added WWW as an answer but beware the documentation says the function is now `Obsolete public Object audioClip; `

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-audioClip.html

Comment: I did not know how to do it, but thanks for letting me know.